# Values from firebase realtime database returns undefined

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I have a problem with getting the value from firebase. Whenever I try to get the value from the grandchildren of `vehicle1` it will return `undefined`.

```
var get_alert = '';
var get_lstCk = '';

var queryRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child('Fred').child('vehicles').child('vehicle1');
queryRef.on('value', function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(query) {
            query.forEach(function(snapshot) {

                 var val = snapshot.val();                                //returns 2020-04-07 and 2020-02-07
                 get_alert = val.battery_and_cables_start_nextDate_alert  //returns undefined
                 get_lstCk = val.battery_and_cables_start_last_checked    //returns undefined

             });
      });
});
```

My database goes like:

```
-users
    |
    |
    --Fred
        |
        |
        --vehicles
              |
              |
              --vehicle1
                    |
                    |
                    --alert
                    |    |
                    |    |
                    |    --battery_and_cables_start_nextDate_alert: "2020-04-07"
                    |
                    --last_checked
                         |
                         |
                         --battery_and_cables_start_last_checked: "2020-02-07"
```

Do I have to make separate queries for `alert` and `last_checked` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both the values are child of alert and last_checked, so try the following code in success snapshot

```
var get_alert = '';
var get_lstCk = '';

var queryRef = firebase.database().ref('users').child('Fred').child('vehicles');
queryRef.on('value', function(querySnapshot) {
      querySnapshot.forEach(function(query) {
            query.forEach(function(snapshot) {

                 var val = snapshot.val();                                //returns 2020-04-07 and 2020-02-07
                 get_alert = val.battery_and_cables_start_nextDate_alert  //returns undefined
                 get_lstCk = val.battery_and_cables_start_last_checked    //returns undefined

             });
      });
});
```

Comment: An error called `TypeError: Cannot read property 'battery_and_cables_start_nextDate_alert' of undefined` appeared

Comment: made changes to above answer, check the above code, i have removed .child(vehicle1) from the query